# Android - modify the adapter and items of a recyclerview in on click listener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My situation is this: I set a recyclerView on runtime in a retrofit method async request, called in a loop. 
So one by one the items are added to the recyclerview.

```
     @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DirectionResults> call, Response<DirectionResults> response) {
            Legs legs = response.body().getRoutes().get(0).getLegses().get(0);
            NearbyBusStation current = new NearbyBusStation(currentItem, legs.getDistance().getValue(), legs.getDuration().getText());

            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < nearbyBusStations.size();i++){
                if (current.getDistance() < nearbyBusStations.get(i).getDistance())
                    break;
            }
            nearbyBusStations.add(i,current);
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(nearbyBusStations.size() - 1);

        }
```

In The adapter:

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    final NearbyBusStation currentItem = mDataset.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(currentItem.getName().getName());
    holder.distance.setText(currentItem.getDistance() +" m");
    holder.time.setText(currentItem.getTime() + " a piedi");
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         //I suppose that code go here
         }
```

I want that when an item of the recyclerview is clicked, it expand adding new element below or that the recyclerview was cleared and the new element are added, with a button to return to initial recyclerview. 
(on the click on a bus stop, it will open the next buses which pass from it)
I've tried to use external libraries to create expandable recyclerview but they work very well with  fixed item, in my case items are adding by retrofit at runtime.
If is correct to use the onclick inside onBindViewHolder, how? with another adapter?
I need to insert items one by one because I used this library for animations

```
  compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.4'
```

which work only inserting or deleting elements one by one, but if is it a problem, I can change library for animation without any problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To answer one point, do not place your `onClick` listener inside `onBindViewHolder`. Each time the view is recycled, the click listener is added. Place your click listener in the constructor of your ViewHolder and use `getAdapterPosition()` to reference the location in whatever Array or List you're using for the RecyclerView.

Comment: @mwieczorek     I add  final NearbyBusStation currentItem =  mDataset.get(getAdapterPosition()); but having a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException